# Add lines and line number to the pseudocode

Tags: algorithms

I am trying to write some pseudocode. How can I add two line to the algorithm at the top and the bottom as well as adding line number.

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{algorithmic}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage[]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetAlgoLined
\KwData{latitude, longitude, mac, route, direction}
%\KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
 initialize $list$ as an empty  list of integers. \\
%\While{not at end of this document}{
%read current\;
$list$ = Get stop Order from behaviour; \\
\eIf{list size > 0}{
  find the last stop name in the behaviour table of this mac;
}{
  find the closet stop of the producer current location; \\
  insert it into next table; \\
  find initializer; \\
  \eIf{initializer is available}{
     get the initializer stop name;  \\
     restore all stop name for this mac to the behaviour table;

  }

}
\caption{Detection algorithm.}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: According to the manual: `\SetNlsty{texttt}{}{}` with `\nl` command before relevant algorithm line, but your example does not compile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `\nl` to a line to insert a line number that can be referenced. Additionally, if you want to add space before/after the `algorithm` environment, you can patch into the `algorithm` environment with some support from [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm2e,lipsum,etoolbox}

\AtBeginEnvironment{algorithm}{\addvspace{2\baselineskip}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{algorithm}{\addvspace{2\baselineskip}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \SetAlgoLined
  \KwData{latitude, longitude, mac, route, direction}
  %\KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
  initialize \texttt{list} as an empty  list of integers \;
  %\While{not at end of this document}{
  %read current\;
  \texttt{list} = Get stop Order from behaviour \;
  \eIf{\texttt{list} size $>$ 0}{
    find the last stop name in the behaviour table of this mac \;
  }{
    \nl find the closet stop of the producer current location \;
    insert it into next table \;
    find initializer \;
    \If{initializer is available}{
       get the initializer stop name \;
       restore all stop name for this mac to the behaviour table \;
    }
  }
  \caption{Detection algorithm.}
\end{algorithm}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Note the use of `\;` to end the line; [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) uses this syntax. It also prints `;`, but you can change this symbol if needed (issue `\DontPrintSemicolon`).

Answer (score 4):

Since the provided 'MWE' is no WE (;-)) I used some dummy code from the `algorithm2e` manual:

The `\nl` command in front of the algorithm line will print the line number, the the style can be set with

`\SetNlSty{font}{txt before}{txt after}` command. The default is `\SetNlSty{textbf}{}{}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetAlgoLined
\SetNlSty{texttt}{(}{)}
%\KwData{latitude, longitude, mac, route, direction}
% initialize $list$ as an empty  list of integers. \\
%$list$ = Get stop Order from behaviour; \\
%\eIf{list size > 0}{
%  find the last stop name in the behaviour table of this mac;
%}{
%  find the closet stop of the producer current location; \\
%  insert it into next table; \\
%  find initializer; \\
%  \eIf{initializer is available}{
%     get the initializer stop name;  \\
%     restore all stop name for this mac to the behaviour table;    
%  }
%} 
%}
\nl\KwIn{input data}
\nl\KwOut{output data}
\nl\tcc{a comment line in C-style}
\caption{Detection algorithm.}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please check my new code. Is it Possible to add one line at the top of the algorithm and one at the bottom?

Comment: @MrAsker: I still can't compile your example. The `\nl` commands can be omitted when needed